# Can't setRequestProperty key to "Authorization", but any other key value will work

Tags: java

I was trying to quickly go over Java by coding a quick and simple oauth2 connection for Twitter, but I've encountered this really strange behaviour when trying to setRequestProperty to request headers.

For instance, if I run the following code to add a request header called "Authorization":

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", b64Keys);
```

My request headers will prints as such and the "Authorization" header will be missing:

> {grant_type=[client_credentials],
>   Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8]}

But if I change the name of the key to "Authorizations" or "test" (or anything else), the setRequestPropert function actually adds the header. Doing so will result in the following output:

> {Authorizations=[Basic
>   WVE0UzNJcmVKUEMYSECRETBASE64CODE2MxWkRNcnNiMg==],
>   grant_type=[client_credentials],
>   Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8]}

Here is the full method:

```
    public String createRequest() throws IOException {
        String tokenBaseURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",publicKey= "",privateKey = "";
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        privateKey = "PRIVATEKEY";
        publicKey = "PUBLICKEY";

        String keyString = publicKey + ":" + privateKey;
        String b64Keys = "Basic "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyString.getBytes());
        System.out.println(b64Keys);

        URL url = new URL(tokenBaseURL);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();


        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", b64Keys);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("grant_type","client_credentials");
        System.out.println(connection.getRequestProperties().toString());

        connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers xsPOST.

        return connection.getContent().toString();

    }
```

Is there something I am missing or is this possibly a bug? I need to be able to add a request header with a key named "Authorization"

Comment: In C# there is a special function which you have to use for the Authorization Header... If you try to set it any other way it will not work... Maybe it's similar in java...

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but I wasn't able to find one.